Wildberries парсинг поисковых запросов
Меня интересует как можно реализовать парсинг всех поисковых запросов, по которому виден товар.
По конкретным запросам для артикула узнать его позиции не проблема.
А как некоторые сервисы, могут только по одному артикулу найти сотни, тысячи поисковых запросов, по которым виден этот артикул и каким позиции он занимает.
В api wb этого нет.

Что такое "парсинг поисковых запросов"?

я вставляю артикул "1234567" - и получаю огромное количество поисковых запросов, по которому можно найти карточка товара с таким артикулом.
Поэтому я подразумеваю что это парсинг

Куда вставляете? Что получаете? Лучше покажите на примерах )

А какова вероятность, что 100% этих запросов сработает? Очень похоже на эвристику поискового движка.

@Kromster например sellego сервис, вставляю артикул. Меньше чем за 5 секунд получаю в моем случае 2000 запросов по которым ВИДНО этот артикул, и какое место он занимает в каждом запросе

Волшебной кнопки не существует, поэтому выдвигайте гипотезы на многоступенчатую обработку данных.
Если бы передо мной стояла такая задача, я бы предложил следующее:

Выгрузить и оцифровать ( добавить в базу данных) - популярные запросы ( крупные сервисы аналитики парсят по этому списку и потом показывают список того, что нашли)

Но чтобы не парсить миллион запросов:

Исходные данные:
Заголовок, описание и характеристики исследуемого артикула
Прямой поиск запросов
Поиск запросов ( из двух и более слов) путём комбинаций
Поиск запросов после лемматизации
Выгрузить похожие товары, конкуренты по запросам из заголовка
провести анализ аналогичный п.1
сделать сводную таблицу, пройтись парсером по ним
(можно словить штрафные санкции от вб) - выгрузить запросы из раздела Товары - карточка товара - продвижение
(если есть Джем) - выгрузить оттуда
спарсить поисковые подсказки

